# Oracle and Powershell return only the first line

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, oracle11g, odp.net

I have a problem with powershell and oracle.

This is my code

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\app\aasif\product\11.2.0\client_2\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

$con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=sys;Password=password;Data Source=myserver/oracle;DBA privilege=SYSDBA")

$con.Open()
$cmd=$con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText="select distinct owner from all_tables where table_name = 'mytable'"

$rdr=$cmd.ExecuteReader()

if ($rdr.Read()) {
  $rdr.GetString(0)
}

$con.Close()
```

When i execute this query directly with SQLPlus, i have :

```
RS123
RS456
RS789
RS741
RS963
```

With my powershell, i can't view all the data returned by the query, but only the first line.

```
RS123
```

How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in place of `if($rdr.Read())` you have to write `while($rdr.Read())` to read and work with all the value from the output of the query.

Actually I am very new in powershell but in general language we have to put this condition in loop.

Answer (score 1):

[`CreateCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10961_01/client4.htm) returns an [OracleCommand](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleCommandClass.htm). [`ExecuteReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/OracleCommandClass.htm#CIHFHHGI) returns and [`OracleDataReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#sthref1316).

Here's and example of using the `OracleDataReader` class:

```
$OracleDataReader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($OracleDataReader.Read()) {
    $OracleDataReader.GetString(0)
}
```

Notice I used [`GetString`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1006481). You'll need to use the data reader method appropriate for the data type of the column corresponding to your SQL query. The available methods are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1004329). If you don't know what the data type is you can use [`GetFieldType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1005058) where the parameter is the column ID you want to check.